# Erro ao exportar para Excel (Arquivo corrompido)

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel, arquivo

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para exportar o resultado de uma consulta *sql* para Excel. Depois do arquivo criado a hora que vou abri-lo ele da um erro de arquivo corrompido.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Execl files (*.xls)|*.xls";
sfd.FileName = "teste";

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Stream s = File.Open(sfd.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(s, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12, 
                      Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, 
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, 
                      true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);         
}
```

[image: Erro após criação do arquivo][image: Mensagem pós reabertura do arquivo]

Comment: Seria possível você disponibilizar um desses arquivos corrompidos?

Comment: Os arquivos estão com 0b não tem como fazer o up do arquivo para te mandar, vc tem alguma ideia como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Então adicione na sua pergunta o trecho de código onde você adiciona o conteúdo ao workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não conheço esta biblioteca e não sei se tem algum problema específico usando ela mas este código está estranho.

Eu imagino que o primeiro parâmetro de `xlWorkBook.SaveAs` seja o nome do arquivo. Então passe o nome do arquivo ali e não um [`Stream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Que por sinal foi aberto sem fazer nada com ele e ele não foi fechado.

O que foi fechado foi o próprio `xlWorkBook`. Provavelmente ele não deveria ter sido fechado ali. Se ele foi aberto em outro lugar este lugar é que deveria ser responsável pelo fechamento. Na verdade o fechamento deveria ser automático. Quando você tenta fechar manualmente você pode ser uma vazamento de recursos se uma exceção for lançada. Poucos programadores se dão conta disto. Testam na situação ótima e esquecem que se algo der errado, você terá uma situação ruim e provavelmente mais difícil de identificar o problema.

Sem conhecer o todo, se entendi a intenção, eu diria que isto resolve o problema (se não resolve, é provável que tenha mais alguma cerrada que não está aparente):

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

sfd.Filter = "Execl files (*.xls)|*.xls";
sfd.FileName = "teste";

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue); //isto deveria estar aqui mesmo?
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/HandleExcel.cs).

E alguma coisa me diz que este `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;` está aí para "esconder" problemas que estão acontecendo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo!